# SvelteKit - API fetches data correctly in javascript but UI fails to render it

Tags: fetch, fetch-api, svelte, sveltekit

+page.svelte:

```
<script>
    import { onMount } from 'svelte';

    let careers = [];

    const fetchCareers = async () => {
        const apiUrl = 'http://localhost:4000/api/v1/careers';

        try {
            const response = await fetch(apiUrl);

            if (!response.ok) {
                throw new Error(`HTTP error! Status: ${response.status}`);
            }

            const data = await response.json();

            careers = data;

            console.log('Updated careers:', careers);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error fetching careers:', error.message);
            console.error(error);
        }
    };

    onMount(fetchCareers);
</script>

<h1>Careers</h1>

{#if careers.length > 0}
    {#each careers as career (career.id)}
        <p>{career.name}</p>
    {/each}
{:else}
    <p>Failed to load careers...</p>
{/if}
```

[image: Image - Browser console fetches data]

careers.length seems to be undefined. Wondering if I am using my if else block incorrectly? I thought this may be a CORS issue with my API but I am able to get my POST function working so I'm unsure why the names aren't being rendered correctly in the browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The screenshot shows that the data has a different shape than what your code is assuming.

The items end up in `careers.data` not directly in `careers`.

Comment: Yes that's it thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Okay figured it out based on the observation from H.B.

Here is my updated code that works to iterate through the names:

```
{#if careers.data}
{#each careers.data as career}
    <p>{career.name}</p>
{/each}
{:else}
    <p>Failed to load careers...</p>
{/if}
```